# How to run multiple reactjs/nextjs applications on a single aws ec2 instance using PM2?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment

I'm looking to deploy two separate ReactJS/NextJS applications on a single AWS EC2 instance using PM2 for process management. I've successfully deployed individual applications using PM2 before, but I'm unsure about how to configure PM2 to manage multiple applications on the same instance effectively. Could someone provide guidance or a step-by-step approach on how to achieve this setup? Any insights into configuring PM2 with multiple applications on a single EC2 instance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

## Nginx Configuration File / default file:-

```
  location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       }

        location /cms {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and **resolved it by modifying the source code with a different base path.**

More details can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/codepunkt/ae82a0f3b9deb93908dc1f3d5bbc8da2)

Comment: I am not using the config.json file to set up my project to run using pm2.